# Inserting Spaces into MATLAB Vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm trying to organize numbers in a vector into an output with spaces at specific areas. So it should come out looking something like this:

```
21212121 545664 35454
```

However when I try to output the string I'm not getting any spacing in between. The spaces are recognized as characters when being input into the vector but I'm not sure that the vector is recognizing the space as an actual space, therefor when I convert it to a string to output it doesn't format correctly.

Answer (score 0):

See this [post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/130915).

In summary there's a few ways:

- matrix concatenation (`horzcat`): `['A', ' ', 'B']`
- or enclose the string in `{}` which will tell `strcat` to respect spaces.

  ```
  strcat({'hello '},{'Anna','Jane','Mark'});
  ```